# Multiple rows of data, need subquery to only pull one row?

Tags: sql, sas

I currently have data like so:

```
 Product_ID IND 1_Revenue 2_Revenue Revenue_Code Channel 
 1          S   $50.        $75.    1               E 
 1.         S   $50.        $75.    2               SE 
 2.         P   $100.       $0.     1               E 
 3.         S   $400.       $60.    1               SE 
 3.         S   $400.       $60.    2               S
```

I am trying to pick when `IND=S`, give me the row with the highest revenue if the `channel= SE`. the revenue code refers to the fields `1_Revenue` and `2_Revenue`.
So in this case I’d expect the output to have 2nd row and the 4th row.

I’ve tried multiple things and nothing has worked. What is the best solution?

Comment: post your expected output, also post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what is meant by the highest revenue. Based on your description, if you just apply a filter to pick rows where IND = S and channel = SE then won't you get rows 2 and 4 out? (as follows)

```
data want;
  set have;
  if IND = 'S' and channel = 'SE';
run;
```

or if you want to use SQL

```
PROC SQL;
  create table want as
  select * from have where IND = 'S' and channel = 'SE';
  quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per our understanding a simple where clause is sufficient to get your result like:

```
  select  Product_ID, IND, 1_Revenue, 2_Revenue, Revenue_Code, Channel
  from yourtable
  where IND = 'S' and Channel = 'SE'
```

If anything else is required then kindly mention it.